# C# and Access database doesn't insert/save my data

Tags: c#, ms-access

I wrote an application with C# and MS Access. I have my form login which it works. OK. And I have an insert statement which does not throw any error, but everything I enter into my `textbox` doesn't get inserted into my database, and when I want to make an update, it returns the same as insert statement, I mean no error, but the row is not inserted or updated.

```
string stringcon = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["rent"].ConnectionString;

private void validateaddmember_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    addmember.Visible = false;

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    pictureBox4.Image.Save(ms, pictureBox4.Image.RawFormat);
    byte[] a = ms.GetBuffer();
    ms.Close();

    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(stringcon);
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;

    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [team]([Firstname],[Lastname],[Email],[Password],[Function],[Role],[Registerdata],[Personaldescription],[Phonenumber],[Picture]) VALUES(@f,@l,@e,@p,@fu,@r,@reg,@per,@ph,@pic) ";

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f", firstname_textbox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@l", lastname_textbox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", email_textbox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ph", phone_textbox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fu", function_textbox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@r", role_dropbox.selectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reg", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH: mm:ss"));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per", richTextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", repeatpassword_textbox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pic", a);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

And here I have in other form my update.

```
string stringcon = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["rent"].ConnectionString;

private void bunifuFlatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//login method
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(stringcon);
    OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand();

    cmd2.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd2.Connection = con;

    cmd2.CommandText ="update [team] set [Numberoflogin] = [Numberoflogin] + 1 where [Email]=@LEMAIL";

    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LEMAIL", materialSingleLineTextField1.Text);

    con.Open();
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: can you launch sql profiler when `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` is executed ?

Comment: Are you sure the Access Database you're looking at is the same as your app is using? If you deploy your access database on a build you might be in for a surprise.

Comment: Please try int affectedRows = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery(); - inside affectedRows you should see the rows affected. If it is 0 your where clause does not find a matching row

Comment: @RahulAgarwal I'm not sure if the Sql Profiler will work with Microsoft Access? Or has the 2016 version evolved that much?

Comment: SQL profiler work only with SQL server, not access database.

Comment: Can you show your connection string?

Comment: @rene i’m sure, my database are the same as the app.

Comment: what does `ExecuteNonQuery` return?

Comment: Did you debug the code? Are the event handlers attached to the events of buttons for sure?

Comment: One thing to remember: the `OleDbCommand` does **NOT** support **named** parameters - but only **positional** parameters. So **you must make sure** to add the parameters to the `OleDbCommand` in the **same order** as they are defined in the `CommandText`. Just giving them the same parameter name does **not** work!

Comment: @marc_s i will try your opinion, and i will Tell you if it work soon!

Answer (score 0):

Along with marc_s's important note -- you switched phone and password, make sure you fix that -- you only need `@` in the sql string. So not

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f", firstname_textbox.Text);
```

but

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Firstname", firstname_textbox.Text);
```

Use the field name (Firstname). @f is just a marker. With Access, you could write the sql string like so:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [team]([Firstname],[Lastname],[Email],
    [Password],[Function],[Role],[Registerdata],[Personaldescription],
    [Phonenumber],[Picture]) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

so when you add the parameter value, use the field name.

You could also open the connection right before `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`, like your update form.